# #include <string.h> or #include <string>

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Does it makes sense to MSVC++ what to include `#include <string.h>` or `#include <string>`? I suppose that both are identical. Am I wrong?

When I do include `#include <string.h>` in my header with function declaration shown below I have the error:

> Error 12  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

```
int userInput(HWND dialogWnd, char *pcResult, int iBufferLen, int iTimeoutSec, int iMinDataSize, int iMaxDataSize, const std::wstring & pcFormHeader, const std::wstring  & pcDefaultText);
```

Comment: These are completely different headers.

Comment: `string.h` is for C string functions. `string` is for C++ `std::string` and related declarations.

Comment: `<string.h>` can also be referred to as `<cstring>` (there are differences in how it interacts with the `std::` namespace).